# Lightning events - clarification regarding APPLICATION events

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I wanted clarification on how the Lightning event framework works. Say for example, if I have page1(with lightning out) and triggered an event from it which is handled by Page2 on click of a button. Pages 1 & 2 are vf pages exposed on public site.
What will happen if a user goes to Page1->clicks a button -->event is fired. Before the user is navigated to the 2nd page, another user from another browser goes to Page1-> clicks a button which fires another event.

How does event handling work for APPLICATION events?
I am implementing something similar and need your thoughts on it, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If two different users fire same event from the different browser then this will not affect. As both are separate thread in browser/server, And they will run separately without any issue. We can run 1000 of thread without any issue.

You will only face issue if they all are trying to updating same records. Which I don't think is your case.

So unless they are operating on their own set of data you don't need to worry about anything here.

Answer (score 0):

Lightning components including events are a JavaScript framework. They run within the context of a browser page. If you navigate across pages then the framework is reloaded, and all previous state is gone.